# Free complete replacement to Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-10, firewall

I'm trying to open some ports on my PC for some multiplayer games, but Windows Firewall makes it impossible to open one. Rather than painstakingly trying to find out what's wrong I'd rather use another app completely or uninstall the default firewall.

To clarify complete replacement: before I had McAfee antivirus/firewall, and when I went into Windows Firewall settings it said the firewall was managed entirely instead by mcafee and I couldn't access the Windows Firewall settings. The McAfee firewall also managed port forwarding for me easily. Likewise, I'm looking for a firewall that would replace the Windows Firewall when accessed via control panel, and would manage open ports. I've tried tinywall and glasswire, but neither of them actually managed port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

You could try ZoneAlarm (https://www.zonealarm.com/uk/software/free-firewall/) - using this tutorial it will allow ports to be opened separate to individual programs (http://loadion.com/en/how_to/Open-Ports-in-ZoneAlarm_40076835.html)